# Rotating a model AND translating it forward in XNA

Tags: xna, models, matrix, movement, rotation

I have this enemy class, and I want it to

1) Spawn at a certain place `Vector3 pos`

2) Rotate to face my player position

3) Move forward

As this code is now, it will appear at it's specified place: `pos`, and attempt to rotate to face it's target: `targetShip`. It fails to correctly face it's target, because of this offset.

If I remove the code that assigns a value to `translation`, or if I normalize `pos` then the model will appear at   the origin and rotate to face it's target correctly.

If I try to move it at all using any of the comment out code regarding `translation`, It appears to start someplace else and I never can find it.

However, if I remove the code relating to `rotation`, and uncomment the code relating to `translation`, then I can get it to move forward.

The trick is doing it all together.

```
    class Enemy : BasicModel
    {


        Matrix rotation = Matrix.Identity;
        Matrix translation = Matrix.Identity;
        public Vector3 pos, up, right, targetShip,dir;

        public Enemy(Model m, Vector3 pos)
            : base(m)
        {
            up = Vector3.Up;
            //sets the position to the Vector3 as it's spawn point.
            translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos);

        }

        public override void Update()
        {
            //Glo is a global class, where I store the player world.
            targetShip = Glo.world.Translation;
            targetShip.Normalize();

          pos = transform.Translation;

          rotation = RotateToFace(targetShip, pos, Vector3.Up);
          //Attempt at moving the model forward. Causes it to go out of view
          //translation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(this.GetWorld().Backward);
          //translation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos);
        }

        public override Matrix GetWorld()
        {
            return rotation * world * translation ;

        }

        /*Params: O = Our target
         * P = Our position
         * U = up.
         * 
         * Code from some site I googled up.
          */
        Matrix RotateToFace(Vector3 O, Vector3 P, Vector3 U)
        {

            //The direction we're facing.
            Vector3 D = (O - P);
            //Our relative Right.
            Vector3 Right = Vector3.Cross(U, D);
            Vector3.Normalize(ref Right, out Right);
            //Our back
            Vector3 Backwards = Vector3.Cross(Right, U);
            Vector3.Normalize(ref Backwards, out Backwards);
            //Our relative up
            Vector3 Up = Vector3.Cross(Backwards, Right);
            //Make a matrix out of all of these.
            Matrix rot = new Matrix(Right.X, Right.Y, Right.Z, 0, Up.X, Up.Y, Up.Z, 0, Backwards.X, Backwards.Y, Backwards.Z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
            return rot;
        }



    }
}
```

### ----

---

This is fixed now, and all this code is mostly obsolete.

Comment: I think your translation computation looks weird: translation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(this.GetWorld().Backward);
translation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos);
If you get this: this.GetWorld().Backward, it calculates with current translation. Than you take result and multiplies translation with it (again). First of all: Shouldn't you reset translation somewhere? Is all that multiplication right?

Comment: What's your exactly question? I couldn't spot any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model's position was coming up as invalid because it's position, {0,0,0} was being normalized.

Also, I changed the RotateToFace method to return a Quaternion.

Answer (score 1):

```
Matrix PlayerAbsoluteTransform;


void UpdatePlayer( Vector3 EnemyPosition, float PlayerVelocity, float Seconds)
{
     Vector3 PlayerPosition = PlayerAbsoluteTransform.Translation;
     Vector3 Forward = EnemyPosition - PlayerPosition;
     Forward.Normalize();

     // This moves your player towars the enemy
     PlayerPosition += Forward * PlayerVelocity * Seconds; 

     // This create the transform matrix for your model, 
     // note that maybe you have to rotate the model before to face right
     PlayerAbsoluteTransform = Matrix.CreateWorld(PlayerPosition, Forward, PlayerUp);
}
```

Comment: With that code, the enemy faces away from the player position, and If I apply the code relating to moving the mesh, it disappears.

Comment: maybe you are not applying transform right...  because I'm sure that if data is right, matrix.CreateWorld returns a right worldmatrix for the object... facing in the forward direction...

Comment: For translating the world forward, I'm using `translation*= Matrix.CreateTranslation(this.GetWorld().Backward);`

Comment: lol... that is bad done... you have to add the translation... and you are multiplying it... you have to think that when you move an object you "add" a translation offset... you should learn some basic algebra before going to make a 3d game...

Comment: It's moving for sure... but you are scaling the position... not very useful and a strange math for translating... I hope you will realize soon... As you can see in this video... I know how it can be done... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WuC60U6z4s&feature=plcp

Comment: Here you are, http://pastebin.com/YCwbGEkx, the code of my Actors who handles logic, and my AnimatedModel who handles model data... Ahh... don't bother, I don't need you tell me if it works... :P

Comment: huh, I'd always wondered what code looks like in a different language. Now I know. Anyway, your code doesn't help me. You just get and set rotation values that you define in another class.

I just want to have an enemy look at me and fly towards me in 3D space. Is that so hard? Apparently, yes, since I haven't gotten a correct answer yet.

Comment: @Blau linear algebra != elementary algebra: notice how `Translation` is a `Matrix` and not a `Vector` in his original code. Please watch your tone "learn some basic algebra before going to make a 3d game" is both derogatory and unwelcome here.

Comment: Ok, I had a mistake with his code... I can assume it... I did not realize that was a matrix... because I assumed that we are talking of my code and I mixed all.. he should note it... and he didn't... and I think that the phrase is not offensive.. is a good advice... if I were right... :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use other way: if you know direction of enemy and position of ship, you can compute angle between current direction of enemy and new direction (ShipPosition - EnemyPosition):
`angle = acos(dot(dir,newdir))`, dir and newdir should be normalized. Also compute "up vector" of this rotation by cross product: `up = cross(dir, newdir)`.

Then try to make rotation matrix according to [this page in section Rotation matrix from axis and angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: I can rotate the enemy to face it's target just fine.

Answer (score 0):

*Some remarks which won't fit in a comment; low quality answer here because it's bed time.*

That code looks nearly right.

I don't like the manual matrix creation (especially if you got it from an OpenGL website: OpenGL [uses a different 'hand' for the co-ordinate system to DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204853.aspx)): instead use the built-in [`Matrix.CreateLookAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.createlookat.aspx).

You might try fiddling with the order of multiplication of the matrices: `a * b != b * a` with matrices.

In addition you are not looking for `Backward`, instead [`Matrix.Invert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.invert.aspx). However, again, it doesn't work like elementary algebra so `a * b * c * Inverse(a) != b * c` - so you will need to recalculate the entire chain of matrices again. [Camera classes](http://www.sgtconker.com/2010/09/article-simple-3d-camera-in-xna/) usually have this information baked in, which you should find extremely useful for your entity class. Basically:

```
// Fiddle with the order; it should give you the general idea though, you 
// can't simply UNDO multiplication in matrices.
var world = Matrix.LookAt(pos, up, ...) * Matrix.Translate(translation, ...) * Matrix.Scale(...);
var wvp = world * view * projection;
```

Comment: He has created another thread.. and it is resolved... :) http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28379/moving-a-rotated-model-in-xna