# Moving a rotated model in XNA

Tags: xna, 3d, models, matrix, rotation

This seems like a simple problem with an equally simple solution that is invisible to me.

I have a model that spawns at the origin and looks at my player model wherever it goes.

I would like it to move forward where it's going. Whenever I try to translate it, it disappears. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

```
public override void Update()
{
    //Glo is a global class, where I store the player's world.
    targetShip = Glo.world.Translation;
    targetShip.Normalize();

    //Rotates the model to face the player's position
    rotation = RotateToFace(targetShip, pos, Vector3.Up);
    pos += Vector3.Normalize(targetShip - pos) * 20f;

}

public override Matrix GetWorld()
{
    // return  rotation * translation * world ;
    return Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(rotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos);
}
```

---

UPDATE:
When I replace:

```
translation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(direction);
```

with

```
translation *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(Vector3.Forward);
```

It now moves forward.

It does not correctly face me, however. It still thinks it's at the origin, and is rotating accordingly.

---

Here is the edited RotateToFace function
The original just returns a Matrix.

```
Quaternion RotateToFace(Vector3 O, Vector3 P, Vector3 U)
{

    //The direction we're facing.
    Vector3 D = (O - P);
    //Our relative Right.
    Vector3 Right = Vector3.Cross(U, D);
    Vector3.Normalize(ref Right, out Right);
    //Our back
    Vector3 Backwards = Vector3.Cross(Right, U);
    Vector3.Normalize(ref Backwards, out Backwards);
    //Our relative up
    Vector3 Up = Vector3.Cross(Backwards, Right);
    //Make a matrix out of all of these.
    Matrix rot = new Matrix(Right.X, Right.Y, Right.Z, 0, Up.X, Up.Y, Up.Z, 0, Backwards.X, Backwards.Y, Backwards.Z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    Quaternion rot2 = Quaternion.CreateFromRotationMatrix(rot);
    return rot2;
}
```

---

Draw code:

```
public void Draw(Camera camera)
{
    Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
    model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

    foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
    {
        foreach (BasicEffect be in mesh.Effects)
        {
            be.EnableDefaultLighting();
            be.Projection = camera.projection;
            be.View = camera.view;
            be.World = GetWorld() * mesh.ParentBone.Transform;

        }

        mesh.Draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to in GetWorld method multiply matrixes in this order:  return rotation * translation *world; btw what is world matrix there?

Comment: I tried that, and that did not seem to change anything.
`world` is read by other classes for hit detection and seems to be the object's real position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't figure out your code, a lot of parts in it don't make sense, such as normalizing the position. But if I understood the problem, you want to make the model to always be looking and moving in the direction of a certain target. And you already have an helper method called `RotateToFace` that takes care of the rotation part.

Then moving the model should really be as simple as taking the direction between itself and the target, and adding that direction to the model's position multiplied by a certain speed factor. Something like:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public Quaternion Rotation { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Target { get; set; }
    public float Speed { get; set; }
    public float MinChaseDistance { get; set; }

    public void Update(float elapsed)
    {
        Rotation = RotateToFace(Target, Position, Vector3.Up);
        if(Vector3.Distance(Target, Position) > MinChaseDistance) 
            Position += Vector3.Normalize(Target - Position) * Speed * elapsed;
    }

    public Matrix GetWorldMatrix()
    {
        return Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(Rotation) *
               Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
    }
}
```

Note: Missed it earlier, but the distance check is actually essential, because if you don't have that and `Target` happens to match `Position`, you'll get a call to `Normalize` on a zero vector, and the `Position` becomes corrupt (i.e. filled with NaNs).

Comment: The RotateToFace function returns a Matrix, so I applied your code accordingly.

However, it didn't work. My model does not move

Comment: @OWiz That's part of the problem. You're doing all of the intermediate calculations with matrices, and it's a mess. You really should be working with simple `position` and `rotation` properties, and the only part in the code that needs to convert it to matrices is the `GetWorldMatrix` method. It would be a lot simpler and cleaner that way. I would recommend trying it in a separate class for starters.

Comment: Okay, well that theory helps. Forgive me for not doing it the "right" way, I don't have much experience in dealing with quats and matrices. I'll try this now.... It doesn't work. Whenever I include the code relating to translating the object, the model appears to vanish.

Comment: @OWiz edit your question by including the code for 'RotateToFace' please

Comment: @Steve H 
There you go.

Comment: @OWiz Regardless of the rotation code, that single `Position += ...` line should be enough to move the model towards the target. If it's  not moving, then it's either that you're not calculating the world matrix correctly, the Position or Target values are wrong, or the Speed is too large.

Comment: @DavidGouveia 
I edited my code in the question to match what I have now. I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @OWiz The part where you call `Normalize` on the target's position should be removed. That really doesn't make sense, and will definitely mess up the results. Other than that, your `Update` method should be taking a `float elapsed` (or a `GameTime gameTime` in which case you have to call `(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds` to get the `elapsed` value) so that you can multiply that by your speed. Otherwise your model will move too fast. In this case it would move 20 units *per frame* instead of 20 units *per second* which is what happens when you multiply *elapsed*.

Comment: @OWiz If that still doesn't work, show us your drawing code. Make sure that you're drawing with the world matrix from `GetWorld()`.

Comment: @David That didn't work, and I updated to show the drawing code.
If the drawing code was wrong, wouldn't it never draw?

Comment: @OWiz I think `be.World = GetWorld() * mesh.ParentBone.Transform;` should probably be this instead: `be.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * GetWorld();`. What you currently have is wrong in two ways, the order of multiplication, and that `mesh.ParentBone.Transform` is relative, not absolute, so you need to use the transforms array that you previously copied the absolute transforms to.

Comment: @David I applied your change and it did not fix anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3298/discussion-between-david-gouveia-and-owiz)